# What is the most sustainable choice to write on a whiteboard?

Tags: diy, alternatives, office

I write a lot on a whiteboard and I would like to find a sustainable alternative to traditional (disposable) [whiteboard markers](http://www.bicworld.com/us/products/details/118/velleda-whiteboard-marker-1701-1751) which are what I'm using right now.

I was thinking of getting a refillable marker like [this alternative](http://www.staedtler.com.au/en/products/markers-refill-ink/refill-stations-refill-ink/lumocolor-whiteboard-refill-station-488-51-refill-station-for-lumocolor-whiteboard-markers-351-and-351-b/) or [any of these](http://www.auspen.us/) but I was wondering if there is any other possible choice. Are there any sustainable alternatives to write on a whiteboard other than refillable markers?

Answer (score 7):

So far the best alternative that I've found is to use a refillable marker. I bought one of [these](http://www.pilotpen.eu/en/products-categories/markers/wytebord-marker-medium-bullet-tip.html) a week ago with a bottle of [ink](http://www.cultpens.com/i/q/PL05519/pilot-wytebord-refill-ink-bottle-wbmatrf). The marker is not made of plastic (I would say it is made of aluminium) except from the cap, so I have reduced a lot the quantity of plastics used. Also, the ink bottle provides around 10 complete refills making it even cheaper than using disposable markers in the long run.